# Is it possible to change the SElinux context of a running process?

Tags: linux, selinux

If a process is already running with a certain SElinux context:

```
system_u:system_r:typea_t
```

Is it possible to change the context of this running process to:

```
system_u:system_r:typeb_t
```

Assuming that typea_t and typeb_t are both valid SElinux types. Can I change the context without terminating the process and running it again using something like runcon?

Alternatively, could I change the properties of typea_t to be the same as the properties of typeb_t while the process is running?

If so, which tool or API would I use to change this, I'm looking for a command line tool or an API I can use with C.

I'm using Centos 7 if that matters.

Comment: @zevzek This is helpful, but I get an error "-bash: echo: write error: Permission denied" when I try to write to `/proc/<pid>/attr/current`  using echo like in your example.

Is it normal to not be able to write to this file? it appears to have 0666 perms so I would expect to be able to.

Comment: I found the following in this [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/28222/):
1) /proc/PID/attr/current represents the current attributes of the process.  In SELinux, this node is used to get the security context of a process, but not to set the security context (a write is always denied)

Comment: @zevzek I think `setcon(3)` is what I was looking for, I believe the process also needs the `setcurrent` permission to be able to change its context. If you want to write up what you've said in these comments as an answer I will accept it.